# Get SharePoint list title in a specified language

Tags: list, development

I need to get a SharePoint list title in a specified language and i am trying to use the `SPUtility.GetLocalizedString` Method:

```
public static string GetLocalizedString(
    string source,
    string defaultResourceFile,
    uint language
)
```

The problem is that i don't know what to place in the `source` parameter, and the default resource file where SharePoint stores list names.

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank tou guys for your answers, the solution was simpler than i thought.

To get an SPList title in a specified language (culture) we can use the `TitleResource` property.

```
splist.TitleResource.GetValueForUICulture(culture);
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at [Localizing SharePoint Solutions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee696750.aspx) and [How to: Add a Resource File](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee231537.aspx) ?

Answer (score 0):

According to the documentation on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.utilities.sputility.getlocalizedstring.aspx), you should use the following:

**source**: An ASP.NET resource expression in the form $Resources:keyname, where keyname is the name half of a name/value pair in a resource file (.resx).

**defaultResourceFile**: The base file name of the language resource file containing a localized string value. For example, if you have a series of resource files named myresources.en-us.resx, myresources.es-es.resx, myresources.de-de.resx, and so on, the value to pass in this parameter is myresources.

In your case, I would think you should use:

```
GetLocalizedString("$Resources:custList", "core", 1033) //1033 for English
```

I got the values from looking at the CustomList definition at C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\14\TEMPLATE\FEATURES\CustomList\ListTemplates\CustomList.xml on my SharePoint installation.

Comment: 'custList' always returns 'Custom List'. If i want to iterate thru all SPlists with what i need to replace it?